# Is there any benefit to turning my Coupons for ingame stuff in after I've progressed a bit in the game?

Tags: black-desert-online

I just bought the Explorer's Package of Black Desert Online which comes with a couple of ingame items/boosts. I noticed those appeared in form of redeemable coupons in my account. So I'm wondering if I should activate those right away or if it's wiser to wait until I've progressed a bit in the game to get the full value out of them.

For example, do the horse/pet/items I receive from the coupons have stats that scale with the player's level? Will activating those coupons right away fill my storage with items I can't really use right away and clog up my inventory? I'm wondering about stuff like this. Not really sure what other possible downsides there could be, so I'd appreciate any active player to give an answer that will help me get the most value out of the extra content. On the other hand, is there anything I *should* activate right away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general the answer is no, though depending on your point of view it's plausible that you may find it worthwhile to wait on **some coupons**

## Things to wait for

Coupons that give items may be worth waiting for due to the fact that they take up space. Given this fact it can be worth expanding your warehouses first to have room to store them and still keep the items you want to store.

One other benefit of waiting longer for consumable items is that they can often be powerful due to their nature of being a bonus, and so it can be worth waiting in order to avoid the temptation to use them in potentially useless situations or on bad gear.

## Things that make no difference

Pets, cosmetics and other items of a similar type are not worth keeping, they will be the same regardless of your character progression. One thing worth noting is that some things can only be redeemed **once**, so it can be good to wait until you find a character you really enjoy playing

House items are cosmetic and so can also be redeemed whenever you like

## Things to use right away

The tier 3 horse token you get from the highest price pack is worth using instantly, as it can be used to get a head start on breeding as well as being quite a powerhouse early on.

Also I would suggest using friend tokens right away ;)